# How to start Azure pipeline from another pipeline in another project?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have 2 projects in Azure DevOps and 1 pipeline in each of them.
I start pipeline in the first project manually.

I need this started pipeline to start another pipeline in the second project.

I cannot use `$(System.AccessToken)` in the REST API call because I get a http 401 error. I suppose due to different project.

How can I start second pipeline? Any automatic way is acceptable.

Comment: do you want to start the second pipeline from the first pipeline?

Comment: @Shayki Abramczyk Yes, I do

Comment: This might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops

Comment: @Murli Prajapati, thank you, can it really trigger pipeline from another project?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Trigger Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks) extension, it allows to trigger a build in a different team project.

[image]